# list sorting node.js using 2 fields

Tags: node.js

Can anyone help me with a sorting problem?

My list is correct sorted by Name. I also use a field called Inactive and has the values 0 and 1.
I like to have the list sorted by 2 fields, first not Inactive and then by name.

Thanks in advance!

```
params.list = sorted.sort((i1, i2) => {
    if (i1.Name.toLowerCase() < i2.Name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if (i1.Name.toLowerCase() === i2.Name.toLowerCase()) return 0;
    if (i1.Name.toLowerCase() > i2.Name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `||` inside sort. Everything you have inside sort right now can be replaced by `a.Name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.Name.toLowerCase())`.

```js
const arr = [{
    Name: 'Foo',
    inactive: 0
  }, {
    Name: 'Boo',
    inactive: 0
  },
  {
    Name: 'Foo',
    inactive: 1
  }, {
    Name: 'Boo',
    inactive: 1
  },
];

const res = arr.sort((a, b) => a.inactive - b.inactive || a.Name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.Name.toLowerCase()));

console.log(res);
```